# Steam autostart

Tags: steam, autostart, startup-applications

After many annoying problems I had to face in Windows, I decided to switch, again, to Ubuntu.

I have installed many apps I find essential for my laptop including Steam. The problem is that I want it to autostart on startup. I know that I need to use Startup Applications. I do not know, however, which file I need to select in the Command bracket.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I just wrote "steam" and it autoruns. See you in another question.

Comment: this is because `steam` is the a system-declared name. on windows you can do something similar, you can execute system declared apps with window+R, also called "Run" (the same will also work in an open command line). On windows only some system apps like "explorer.exe" are declared and will work, on a linux that provides package managing such as ubuntu, all installed apps must have a declared name. fortunately "steam" was not already reseved so valve was able to register "steam" as the package name  for their client. Typing `steam` into a terminal will run the Steam client. startup is a term.